# Generic completion handler in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, closures

I have a method which has a method named `performRequest()`. It takes a `JSONRequest` parameter. `JSONRequest` looks something like this:

```
public typealias JSONCompletionHandler = ([Entity]?, NSError?) -> Void

public class JSONRequest: Request {
    public var completionHandler: JSONCompletionHandler
    public var endPoint: String
}
```

And `performRequest()` looks like this:

```
public func performJSONRequest<T where T: Entity>(jsonRequest: JSONRequest, _: Type) {
        // Make a request which returns a data object
        var entities = self.convertJSONData(data, jsonKey: jsonRequest.jsonKey, T.self)
        // Error: 'T' is not identical to 'Entity'
        jsonRequest.completionHandler(entities, error)
}
```

As you can see, it calls `convertJSONData()` which looks like this:

```
func convertJSONData<T where T: Entity>(jsonData: AnyObject, _: T.Type) -> [T] {
        // Convert the data into Swift collection classes, enumerate over them, and create model objects
        var json = JSON(data: jsonData as NSData, options: nil, error: nil)
        var entities = [T]()

        for obj in json {
            let book = T(json: obj)
            entities.append(book)
        }

    return entities
```

Entity is a protocol which all my model classes, for example `Author` and `Book`, conform to.

It defines one method: `init(json: JSON)`. Since `T` is defined as `T:Entity`, I can just call `T:(json: obj)` to create instances of any class conforming to `Entity`.

I want to be able to use `performJSONRequest()` to perform request for *any* object conforming to Entity. For example, I want to build a request for Book instances like this:

```
var request = JSONRequest(endPoint: "books") { (let object: [Entity]?, let error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // Cast object to [Book] and have fun
}

performJSONRequest<Book>(request)
```

I can't for the life of me find out how I would implement this. Right now, I get an error in the `performJSONRequest()` method saying `'T' is not identical to 'Entity'`. If I define the array in the completion handler as `[AnyObject]` I get the same error: `'T' is not identical to 'AnyObject'`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is to move the generic type up into the `JSONRequest` class - that way `JSONCompletionHandler` can be defined with the generic type you're requesting instead of just the `Entity` protocol. (Some of your code seemed a little pseudo-, so this might need some tweaking to fit back into your implementation.)

`JSONRequest` is now a generic class with an `Entity` type restraint:

```
public class JSONRequest<T: Entity>: Request {
    // completion handler defined in terms of `T`
    public typealias JSONCompletionHandler = ([T]?, NSError?) -> Void

    // no further changes        
    public var completionHandler: JSONCompletionHandler
    public var endPoint: String
    public init(endPoint: String, completionHandler: JSONCompletionHandler) {
        self.endPoint = endPoint
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
    }
}
```

`performJSONRequest` doesn't need the type passed as a separate parameter any more. Since `jsonRequest` is specialized, it gets the type information from that parameter:

```
public func performJSONRequest<T: Entity>(jsonRequest: JSONRequest<T>) {
    // create array of `T` somehow 
    var entities: [T] = []
    var error: NSError?

    // completionHandler expects [T]? and NSError?
    jsonRequest.completionHandler(entities, error)
}
```

When creating your `JSONRequest` instance, the type given in the completion handler (e.g., `[Book]?`) will set the type for the generic `JSONRequest`, and hold throughout the process:

```
var request = JSONRequest(endPoint: "books") { (books: [Book]?, error) in
    println(books?.count)
}
performJSONRequest(request)
```

Comment: That's fantastic. I didn't realize that defining `JSONCompletionHandler` within `JSONRequest` would allow it to use its `T` type placeholder. Thank you so much for your complete answer!